# Custom gradient in border is not working when stacked

Tags: html, css, z-index

I have this example where I'm trying to make borders with gradients in CSS: https://codesandbox.io/s/sparkling-pine-uvdcj?file=/src/styles.css

As you can see, I am able to show the border in the first card, the one that is not stacked into a container (just a simple div with a background).

When I put the same component into another element (as the container), I'm not able to show the border at all.

What is the problem?

Here the CSS and HTML:

```css
body {
  background-color: gray;
}

.container {
  background-color: black;
  padding: 10px;
  margin: 10px;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 32px;
  width: 300px;
  height: 180px;
  border-radius: 32px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #1b1a1f, #1b1a1f 65%, rgba(77, 58, 40, 1));
  box-shadow: 0px 10px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.card:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 182px;
  width: 302px;
  border-radius: inherit;
  margin: -1px;
  background: linear-gradient(40deg, #1b1a1f, #1b1a1f 60%, #ffb966 90%);
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div class="card"></div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is happening because you have given the `.card:after` `z-index` of `-1`. Whereas the default `z-index` is `auto` or you can think of it as `0`.

So, the `container` has the `z-index` of `auto` which is higher than the  `z-index` of `.card:after`. That is why it is behind the `black` background.

---

**You can do so by:**

- Adding the below styles to the `.container`.

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: -2;
}
```

> Check it in action on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/manaskhandelwal1/pen/MWbGmQO).

Comment: Oh! That's nice. But... Is It possible to put that z-index stuff in card:before? I mean, in that way I have to be aware of where I put that card in order to modify the z-index of the parents... Can I make it independent of the parents?